# Is there any free recommended Tune-up utilities/softwares to “Optimize” your system?

Tags: windows, gratis, optimization

I have been looking for a while websites which recommend using different "Tune-up utilites" or "system utilities" to improve performance to the system.
I do have Windows 10, 64 bits.

So I have just read generally the typical recommendation to ccleaner and some free software to defrag your system but that's it.

Would appreciate any info you can bring me.

Comment: This is a bit broad. Do you have any particular optimization in mind? Disk space? Speed? Anything else? have you tried anything? If so, what, and what features did you fell that it was missing? Also, please note that I added the [tag:gratis] and [tag:windows] tags. If you do this in future, it will help us to help you. Welcome aboard. I hope that you get an answer :-)

Comment: A little out of date, but might give you a start ... https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-tune-up-program-for-computer.htm

Comment: Hey mawg, greetings. I'm sorry will try to explain better. I have tried already ccleaner, defrag, check disk, booting services, secondary services working at idle. So would like to know if there is really needed to use one of those "tune-up" utilities softwares around internet which promise to speed up as much as possible or if any of them is really worth it. The free version of any of them is lacking of like half functions. However ccleaner at least have the most "interesting-important" activated. Would appreciate your opinion, if you experience with this subject.

Answer (score 1):

This can be rather opinionated as there are a number of methods or approaches on could take.

For example, I could suggest [Wise 365](https://www.wisecleaner.com/wise-care-365.html) as a free option to maintain your system, or you could use the free suite of tools available for [Auslogic](https://www.auslogics.com/en/)- there are so many tools that promise to perform the same tasks.

However, there are built-in Windows tools to perform such tasks:

- [Disk Cleanup](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026616/windows-disk-cleanup-in-windows-10)
- [MSConfig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSConfig) for services
- `shell:startup` and Task Manager for startup entries

Comment: Note I will actually revise this *answer* at a later stage with findings and a better recommendation.